# How to fetch data from mongodb and display the data in datagridform in windows forms c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms, datagridview

can anyone please help how to fetch data from Mongodb and display that data in Datagridview. here i tried this one.can anyone give better answer

```
        var ConnectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
       // var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = client.GetDatabase("testdb1");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("tablo1");

        //var entity = collection.FindAll();

        BindingList<Entity> doclist = new BindingList<Entity>();

        foreach (var deger in collection.Find(doclist))

            doclist.Add(deger);
            //string[] row1 = new string[] { deger.deger1.ToString() };
            //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
```

Comment: `here i tried this one` Does this code work? Why do you want an alternative?

Comment: Why do you want an alternative -> [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this one:

```
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("DB Name");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Class Name>("Table Name");

        List<Class Name> list = await collection .Find(x => true).ToListAsync();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list
```

Comment: @jyothi best way of thanking on Stack Overflow is to mark the working solution as [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Happy coding